# Boolean false Feed Me data is not being processed

Tags: plugin-feedme, craft4

I have a feed that needs to map data to a lightswitch field. When the API returns data for that field that equates to boolean true, it works fine. But when the data equates to boolean false ("false" "no" "0"), the data is being removed from processing.

After running the feed, I go to Logs and expand one of the items. The "{{ feed name }}: Data ready to import" item shows all data returned from the API except the one that needs to be mapped to the lightswitch. Again, it's only removed when the value equates to boolean false.

So when running the feed, the lightswitch is able to move from off to on, but not from on to off.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the returned API data?

Comment: @CraftQuest ```{"ID":"9643c70f12343dk0e039a093a0a1544","name":"Darth Vader","objCode":"USER","homeGroupID":"5e5020c201c4edc31aea2a26","firstName":"Darth","lastName":"Vader","title":"Sith Lord","emailAddr":"darth@vader.com","phoneNumber":"15551231234","phoneExtension":"3223","DE:Employee Type":"FTE","DE:Executive Team":"0","DE:User is Remote":"Yes"}``` - The Executive Team item is the one in question.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed in [v5.14](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/releases/tag/5.1.4).